# MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

My Cordova program executes in the browser without build errors.  When I try to send it to my Android Phone via debug build to the device (F5) I get this build error in the output window:

```
MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

The message up to failure from the output window is:

```
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
Reading build config file: C:\Users\S50A\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClockJsAN\ClockJsAN\build.json
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\S50A\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClockJsAN\ClockJsAN\platforms\android\gradlew.bat" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\S50A\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClockJsAN\ClockJsAN\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true""
Command finished with error code ENOENT: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\S50A\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClockJsAN\ClockJsAN\platforms\android\gradlew.bat" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\S50A\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ClockJsAN\ClockJsAN\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
1>Done building project "ClockJsAN.jsproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

It is clear which command from the above failed, but not clear to me how to fix it.  ENOENT seems to mean that something wasn't found.

(i.e. the cmd /s /c ... generated the error).

I notice I have no plugins installed in config.xml.  Could this be what it is looking for?  I also notice that I get the same error when I attempt to install the Cordova Media Plugin via config.xml.  Please Advise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this also happens when creating a new, blank Cordova App then something in your system is not correctly setup. The only plugin that you should always add to any app is the **device** plugin.

Follow this guide to ensure you have installed all the required tools:
[Configure the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/)

Ensure you are using the **x86 versions** of Java, Node, Git and other tools. I'm using [Node 4.8.4](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), the latest from the 4 branch. Also you need to install the Android SDK using [SDK Manager GUI](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip). This tool does not require Android Studio.

If all else fails, repair your Visual Studio installation and/or reinstall the [Apache Cordova tools](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/).

Comment: Thanks to andreszs' advice, after a clean install I was able to create a new, blank Cordova App. I am now only using the built in default tools and extra options in Visual Studio for Apache Cordova apps that I can code. (I am running a default install of Android Studio side by side with no interference)